# Updating service worker when assets change

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cli, service-worker, ngx-translate

I noticed my Angular build (using Angular-cli) isn't updating my translation (using [ngx-translate](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core) - not even after deleting the cache from the browser.

On my `angular-cli.json`, I've set `serviceWorker` to `true`. I tried switching it to `false` and the updated translated files were displayed correctly. So, I guess the service worker isn't updating my translation files when generating a new build.

Any ideas how I ensure my assets will be updated when they change? Does the `angular-cli` support any way of configuring our service worker prior the build? I didn't find much information about it in their [documentation](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki).

Answer (score 1):

If the translations are cached, you need to change the `cacheName` into your service worker activation.

i.e.:

```
var cacheName = 'myAppCache-3s';
var filesToCache = [
 '/'
  'index.html',
  'scripts/hammer.min.js',
  'images/play_white.svg', 
  'images/stop_white.svg',
  'images/back_white.svg',
  'images/forward_white.svg',
  'images/sfondo.jpg',
  'images/ic_refresh_white_24px.svg',
  'scripts/meteo-zoom.js',
  'scripts/meteosurf_200.js',
  'scripts/jquery3-2-1.min.js',
  'scripts/jqueryui1-12-1.min.js',
  'styles/inline_01.css',
  'styles/meteosurf_200.css',
  'styles/jqueryui-smoothness.css',
  'styles/images/ui-bg_glass_65_ffffff_1x400.png',
  'styles/images/ui-icons_454545_256x240.png',
  'images/icons/icon-64x64.png',
];
```

When I change the assets, I always change the cacheName, adding a new version at the end of the name (i.e.: `var cacheName = 'myAppCache-3t';`).

If your service worker has previously been installed, but then a new version of the worker is available on refresh or page load, the new version is installed in the background, but not yet activated. It is only activated when there are no longer any pages loaded that are still using the old service worker. As soon as there are no more such pages still loaded, the new service worker activates.

But you can force this behaviour with the `skipWaiting()` function:

```
self.addEventListener('install', function(e) {
  console.log('[ServiceWorker] Install');
  e.waitUntil(
    caches.open(cacheName).then(function(cache) {
      console.log('[ServiceWorker] Caching app shell');
      return cache.addAll(filesToCache);
    }).then(function() {
        return self.skipWaiting();
    })
  );
});
```

Comment: Yeah, but I'm using [angular-cli](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli). I wonder if there's a command (or variable I can set) to do that during the build (the service worker is generated automatically during the build).

Comment: Don't know much about angular-cli but you should have a worker-basic script somewhere in your dist folder.